# MYSQL speed of this query and optimized table structure

Tags: mysql

I need to build a new table system, it'll store an id and 10 `varchars(255)` per id. That is all it will need to store. Other than the obvious insert/delete/update on whole rows only, the only other query that will be run is a `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='id'`. 7 million records.

I have 2 structures I came up with, which are:

(1) - single table, id,then 10 `varchars`, no joins, nothing fancy, id is primary key, simple `select *`.

(2) - 2 tables, first has id, then 10 integer elements, second has `integer(auto increment)` and the `varchars`. This would use a join. Hence, I would guess 10 joins per query.

Clearly 2 is better as a formal structure and for later table structural changes, BUT, in terms of **SPEED** of querying alone, which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will always be storing exactly `10` `VARCHAR` fields and each `VARCHAR` has its own meaning (like it's always a name, or always an address etc.), then just create a table with `10` fields.

Your second solution is called `EAV` (entity-attribute-value), which is mostly used for sparse matrices (when you have lots of possible attributes with only few of them being set for a given entity). It is scalable and maintainable, but will be less efficient for the query like yours.

Comment: @David: first one (with all values in a single row). "Less efficient" in the `EAV` description means "slow" :)

Answer (score 0):

definitely in terms of speed the first one is better. Joins are really slow on big tables

Comment: Can I get confirmation on "joins are really slow on big tables" please.  I index the id column on table1 and integer column on table2

Comment: if you imagine what happens in joins its clear why they are slow in big tables.